# App crashes on searching (filtering) the NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, search

So I have the following code:

My .h file

```
    @interface TableViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
    IBOutlet UISearchBar *mysearchBar;
        NSMutableArray *filteredList;
     BOOL isFiltered;
}
@property NSDictionary *iconSet;

@end
```

and the part of the .m file where things go wrong.

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

if(searchText.length == 0)
{
    //bool in .h file
    isFiltered = NO;
}else
{
    isFiltered = YES;
    filteredList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //self.iconSet is an NSDictionary (coming from a segue) formed like -(NSDictionary *) symbols { return self.symbols = @{@"":@"Heart With Arrow",@"❤️":@"Heavy Black Heart"}
    for (NSDictionary *theDictionary in self.iconSet) {

        for (NSString *key in theDictionary) {
            NSString *value = [theDictionary objectForKey:key];
            NSRange stringRange = [value rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

            if (stringRange.location != NSNotFound) {
                [filteredList addObject:theDictionary];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
[myTableView reloadData];
}
```

xCode is not barking at me with any errors or warnings, but when I press a letter or icon in my searchbar, the app crashes, and it gives the following message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1000f94d0'

I've tried looking it up on stackoverflow, but haven't found the answer I was looking for. I'm hoping someone here can help me find my (probably stupid) mistake.

Comment: yes I think so, the Dictionary is build with @{@"":@"Heart With Arrow"}, where both items are NSStrings

Comment: I don't think you need to loop through each dictionary in self.iconSet as it IS a dictionary itself not an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `self.iconSet` is a dictionary, iterating over it with `for..in` will give you the keys as strings. Thus, second loop is not needed:

```
for (NSString *key in self.iconSet) {
    NSString *value = [self.iconSet objectForKey:key];
    ...
}
```

or better:

```
[self.iconSet enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSString *value, BOOL *stop) {
     ...
}]
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I used the better part and the filtering now works (although I need to tweak it a bit more, to make it search for both keys and values, currently keys don't give any results).

Comment: Thanks once again, I got it to work fully now by editing some of my other code to filter a dictionary, and using your enumerateKeysAndObjects